# Phone is continuously rebooting/restarting

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, reboot

I have Old micromax phone which runs on Android kitkat. **For some reason i switched off/power of the phone**. But now when, I press power button, it is continuously restarting.(without appearance of home screen).

I even charged battery to full and even checked that battery is loose or not, there is no problem regarding battery.

Even i had done factory data reset and wipe out the cache partition(by pressing power button and volume key simultaneously and then selecting factory data reset option and remove cache partition option) But that doesn't work!

Phone is continuously restarting! **To stop it** , i had to manually remove the battery and then put it back again. **But again** when i press power button, the condition becomes same, it is continuously restarting/rebooting.

Is there is anyway i can fix it by myself? Please help

Comment: Bootloader unlocked, device rooted? How long does one reboot cycle take (in seconds)?

Comment: @Robert sir, device is not rooted. One Reboot cycle take maximum 7-9 seconds(home screen does not appear.) Please help

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you mean with "But that doesn't work!" when you tried to perform a factory reset. If there are error messages please typewrite them and add it to your question.

Comment: @Robert sir, by "that doesn't work" i mean, problem is not solved. That is, though factory data reset is complete but when i press reboot option then phone start but home screen does not appears and then it continues to restart restart restart.....so on